# registration form error handling: remember correct fields

Tags: php, html, registration

I'm writing a registration form with html/php. However, I also included a captcha, which will be verified by my php-scripts after the user has submitted the form.

In case the captcha was wrong, I don't want the user having to retype everything into the form again. How can I pre-fill the information that was already entered back into those fields?

Comment: Ajax the captcha

Comment: You could use ajax to send the catcha value to the script before submiting the form

Comment: "How can I pre-fill the information that was already entered back into those fields?"...get the field values back out of the $_POST variables and use them to re-populate the HTML when you generate it. Without seeing your actual code it's hard to give any more specific advice than that.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I disagree, because someone can then just bypass that and make the final submit request directly. It's trivial to switch off JS, or just make a separate HTTP request to the endpoint using any tool. Captcha's are primarily designed to defeat bots, which are the precisely the kind of agents which will not give a fig about ajax calls or client-side validation. The captcha needs to be validated at the same time the rest of the form is submitted, otherwise it's useless. That doesn't prevent the OP from re-populating the correctly submitted fields when re-loading the page.

Comment: @mplungjan I disagree, because someone can then just bypass that and make the final submit request directly. It's trivial to switch off JS, or just make a separate HTTP request to the endpoint using any tool. Captcha's are primarily designed to defeat bots, which are the precisely the kind of agents which will not give a fig about ajax calls or client-side validation.

Comment: @ADyson How would I successfully submit the form without the solved captcha value?

Comment: @mplungjan again we're somewhat speculating without the OP's code, but there's a pattern where you check the captcha value server-side (the server code makes a request to google). I think it's important to do that if you want to be sure the form was not tampered with. Therefore it means you can submit the form with or without a correct captcha value, and you only find out if it's valid once the server sends you a response. Equally a non-browser agent could attempt to submit data to the server without ever having actually encountered the captcha - again the server must check for that

Comment: @mplungjan for instance, for google's recaptcha the server-side verification scenario is described here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify . The main documentation page describing usage also explains that the final step in the process is to send the captcha value to the backend to verify it. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3 .

Comment: @ADyson Thank you. That was exactly what I wanted. It was a very general question, and I wanted a general answer :-)

Comment: @ADyson Yes, that is what I meant by _How would I successfully submit the form without the solved captcha value_ - the idea being that the server knows if the captcha was solved when the payload of the form arrives regardless of client sending it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are rendering on the post request only here is a sample code you can use

```
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="name" value=<?php echo $_POST["name"];?>>
// Code for captcha
</form>
```

Do remember to sanitize the POST according to your use case or it would lead to **XSS** on your form.

Comment: thank you. I didn't even think about sanitizing the input values.